# creating intrusion detection system with shell script

Tags: shell

i have UNI work where i have to create a shell script that monitors a directory with a few text files that can inform you (can be manual check to be informed) if they have been modified. honestly im not sure where to start and im bad at linux and cant find anything to help. i can only use standard tools in ubuntu. any help would be great. thankyou

update - this is what i have so far and i need a way to verify that the values printed are the same after altering a file (if they are not the same then print whats files have been changed)

also sorry first time using the site trying to learn..

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "press 1 to check - press 2 to exit"

while :
do
    read INPUT_STR
    case $INPUT_STR in
        1)
            echo "checking sums"
    md5sum Target/bob
    md5sum Target/bec
    md5sum Target/john
    md5sum Target/mary
    md5sum Target/mike
            ;;

        2)
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "incorrect input"
    esac
done

echo "thankyou for using IDS"
```

Comment: Do you need information that files were modified in some period (last 6 hours) or since last check?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
#!/bin/bash

WORKDIR=/home

TARGETS=(
"$WORKDIR/bob"
"$WORKDIR/bec"
"$WORKDIR/john"
"$WORKDIR/mary"
"$WORKDIR/mike"
)

for target in "${TARGETS[@]}"; do
    md5file="${target##*/}.md5"
    if [[ -e "$md5file" ]]; then
        md5sum --quiet -c "$md5file"
    else
        echo "create md5sum referenz file $md5file"
        md5sum "$target"/* > "$md5file"
    fi
done
```

At first run it creates for every directory a reference file. On the second run the directory will be compare with reference file. Modifications will be shown. When you delete one reference file, it will be created again on the next run.

**explanation**

```
# loop over the array with the targets
for target in "${TARGETS[@]}"; do

    # remove all directories except the last, append .md5
    # and assign it to the variable md5file
    md5file="${target##*/}.md5"

    # if md5file exists, use it as reference and check if
    # modifications where happend 
    if [[ -e "$md5file" ]]; then

        # use the md5file as reference and only show
        # modified files, ignore ok messages
        md5sum --quiet -c "$md5file"

    else
        # when no md5file exists

        echo "create md5sum referenz file $md5file"

        # use target, append /* to it and run md5sum
        # redirect output to md5file (reference file for next run)
        md5sum "$target"/* > "$md5file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: your a legend, somehow i got it to work for the folders i wanted, if you could would you be able to explain a little on what's going on with the code, as I'm literally 2 months into basic Linux work i don't really understand what's doing what from line 13 to 19 and I'm here to learn rather than copying someone else's work
thanks a bunch though